# Paramatrizes curve with constant speed

Tags: differential-geometry

Show that if $\alpha : I \rightarrow \Re^{n+1}$ is a parametrised curve with constant speed then $\alpha(t) \perp \frac{d}{dt} \alpha(t)$ for all $t\epsilon I$.

Comment: This is false.  Any smooth curve can be re-parametrized using its so-called [arc length parametrization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_curves#Length_and_natural_parametrization) so that the motion along the curve has constant speed.  Thus, your statement implies that the position vector for an object is always perpendicular to it's velocity vector, which need not happen. Perhaps you mean for the curve to have constant magnitude?

Comment: @MarkMcClure Or, perhaps what's meant is $\alpha'(t) \perp \tfrac{d}{dt} \alpha'(t)$ for all t?

Comment: I mean to ask whether it is true that if the parametrization is such that the speed is constant, then the velocity vector is perpendicular to the position vector. Please give some counter example in case it is not true.

Comment: Counterexample: Pick any curve $\alpha(t)$ with constant non-zero speed.
If $\alpha(t) \not\perp \dot{\alpha}(t)$ for some $t$, then we are done. Otherwise,
consider the curve $\beta(t) = \alpha(t) + \dot{\alpha}(0)$. $\beta(t)$ is again a curve with constant speed but $\beta(t) \not\perp \dot{\beta}(t)$ near $t = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the following.

Consider, for instance, a curve $\alpha$ in $\Bbb R^2$ such that $\alpha(t)=(t,0)$. Then 
$\alpha’(t)=(1,0)=\text{const}$, but the vectors $\alpha(t)$ and 
$\alpha’(t)$ are collinear, not orthogonal. But two other facts hold. If $|\alpha(t)|=R=\text{const}$ then $(\alpha(t), \alpha(t))=R^2$ and $2(\alpha’(t), \alpha(t))=(\alpha(t), \alpha(t))’=(R^2)’=0,$ so the vectors $\alpha(t)$ and $\alpha’(t)$ are orthogonal. Similarly, if $|\alpha’(t)|=R=\text{const}$ then $(\alpha’(t), \alpha’(t))=R^2$ and $2(\alpha’’(t), \alpha’(t))=(\alpha’(t), \alpha’(t))’=(R^2)’=0,$ so the vectors $\alpha'(t)$ and $\alpha’’(t)$ are orthogonal.